# Does Windows 10 support CubeCraft?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Yesterday, I bought the Windows 10 beta version of Minecraft. My daughter wants to play CubeCraft, but I cannot connect to the play.cubecraft.net server.

I opened the port in the firewall, so that is not the solution. Can anyone tell me if she can play CubeCraft games in Win10? What do we need to do?

Comment: You do not need Windows10 edition to play on Windows 10. Regular minecraft works just fine and they are two completely different versions of the game.

Answer (score 8):

The Windows 10 version of Minecraft is essentially the pocket edition, and cannot connect to conventional servers that are for the Java version of Minecraft.

If you want to connect to PC Minecraft servers, you need the PC Java version of Minecraft, which does work on Windows 10.

If you want to connect to Pocket Editon servers, the Windows 10 version or mobile versions can connect to them.

Answer (score 3):

**No.**

Windows 10 edition of Minecraft can only connect to Minecraft: Bedrock Edition servers, not Java Edition servers.